# the bashrc file is not working when I docker run --mount bashrc

Tags: bash, docker, alias

I'm testing an app on docker (search engine) but when I use `docker run` the `bashrc` doesn't work if for example there was an alias inside `bashrc`, I can't use it.
The file `bashrc` is copied to the container but still can't use it.
My question is why not? is it only because that `bashrc` needs to be reloaded or there is another reason?

```sh
sudo docker run \
     --mount type=bind,source=$(pwd)/remise/bashrc,destination=/root/.bashrc,readonly \
     --name="s-container" \
     ubuntu /go/bin/s qewrty
```

Comment: When I run this command, Docker tries to use the default "ubuntu" image which is provided in the big default Docker container registry. That image doesn't know what `/go/bin/s qewrty` means. Is your container different than the default ubuntu container? Does it have an executable at `/go/bin/s`?

Comment: If I map in my own bashrc into a running container which has bash installed, then use `docker exec -it s-container bash` then it starts a bash shell and that bash profile does get loaded just fine. I suspect there's something going wrong eg. you're not actually starting a bash shell when you're trying to use bash.

Comment: @sinback yes actually `s` is an executable that I have installed on the image with Dockerfile, but `s` doesn't matter here, what matters is that `bashrc` isn't loaded when i use `docker run` you can test that with creating a `bashrc` file that contain an alias for example, let's say `alias lsa="ls -a"` then try mounting the file on the container and use `/bin/bash/lsa` as an executable, I want to know why it won't work

Comment: I'm confused by what you described in your last comment that you're trying to do. To be clear, /bin/bash/lsa is not going to be an executable you could use - not sure if that was a typo or not. /bin/bash is a file for you, so /bin/bash/lsa isn't going to be anything unless you replace your /bin/bash file with a /bin/bash directory with an 'lsa' file in it for some reason.

Comment: bashrc files are for use with interactive shells, which isn't going to be what your docker container uses by default. Even outside your container, if you try to run "/bin/bash lsa" you're going to get problems. Interactive shells are different from just running the bash executable.

Comment: It seems that the underlying problem is that you don't understand what the .bashrc file is for. Your question doesn't explain the problem you're having, only that your expectations were not met. You say that you "can't use [an alias]" but have not shown any attempt to use an alias. I've voted to close this question because I can't reproduce an error that you've haven't explained. If you can fix the problems with the question and explain what is going wrong for you then I'll remove this comment and my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start your container as

```sh
docker run ... image-name \
  /go/bin/s qwerty
```

when Docker creates the container, it *directly* runs the command `/go/bin/s qwerty`; it does not invoke bash or any other shell to do it.  Nothing will ever know to look for a `.bashrc` file.

Similarly, if your Dockerfile specifies

```sh
CMD ["/go/bin/s", "qwerty"]
```

it runs the command directly without a shell.

There's an alternate shell form of `CMD` that takes a command string, and runs it via `/bin/sh -c`.  That *does* involve a shell; but it's neither an interactive nor a login shell, and it's invoked as `sh`, so it won't read any shell dotfiles (for the specific case where `/bin/sh` happens to be GNU Bash, see [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files)).

Since none of these common paths to specify the main container command will read `.bashrc` or other shell dotfiles, it usually doesn't make sense to try to write or inject these files.  If you need to set environment variables, consider the Dockerfile `ENV` directive or an entrypoint wrapper script instead.